# iPad app for reading and writing guitar tablature

Tags: ipad, music

I'm looking for an iPad app for guitar tabs reading and writing. I'd prefer that one had an auto scroll feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading tabs, I like [Songsterr Plus](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/songsterr-plus/id399211291?mt=8), have heard good things about [TabToolkit](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tabtoolkit/id325946571?mt=8) too. For writing tabs, [Progression](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/progression/id424281020?mt=8) and [Guitar Script](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/guitarscript-mobile-guitar/id437151862?mt=8) supposedly both quite good, haven't tried either of them myself, though.

Comment: Links are awesome.

Comment: Please add some links to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, links seemed a bit superfluous when there's only one place you can buy iPad apps anyway. Fixed now.